# How to search for records in default search view in Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

By default search results giving only by 1st columns(field) record i.e customername. But I'd like to search some records with other column names. Any help?? Thanks in advance

[image]

Here is the code for my search view..

```
<record id='Booking_search' model='ir.ui.view'>
        <field name="name">Book A Room.search</field>
        <field name="model">book.room</field>
        <field name="type">search</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <search  string='first'>
                <group string='Customers with Incomplete Details'>
                   <field name='mobile'/> -->
                   <filter string="No Address" domain="[('address','=',False)]"/>
                   <field name='name'/>

                <filter string="No Mobile" domain="[('mobile','=',False)]"/>
                <field name='name'/>

                </group>

            </search>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use only those fields which are defined in search view.

For this you need to pass proper key and value in context.key should like this

search_default_filter_name

Example: In res_partner search view there is one filter like this

```
<filter string="Persons" name="type_person" icon="terp-personal" domain="[('is_company','=',0)]"/>
```

If you want this filter as default pass context like this

```
 <field name="context">{"search_default_customer":1,"search_default_type_person":1}</field>
```

If you don't want search_default_customer use {"search_default_type_person":1} instate of passing like this {"search_default_customer":0,"search_default_type_person":1}

You can also use field from search view

```
<field name="parent_id" filter_domain="[('parent_id','child_of',[self])]"/>
```

for use field pass context like this {"search_default_parent_id":1}

hope this will help